# 'No space left on device' when running a pipeline after adding additional storage

Tags: git, gitlab, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, diskspace

After purchasing the additional storage (10GB) on Gitlab and running the pipeline I'm running into problems related to space left on the device. I ran the "df -h" command to check the storage and this is what came back (this command was run before the pipeline operation that exhausted the device space):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail   Use%    Mounted on
overlay          21G   15G  5.9G    72%     /
tmpfs            64M   0    64M      0%     /dev
tmpfs            1.8G  0    1.8G     0%     /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M   0    64M      0%     /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        21G   15G  5.9G    72%     /builds
```

This is part of the log where the error happens:

```
2023/01/16 18:35:12 Adding files to temp tarball
Error: write /builds/myNamespace/sps/output/.temp/project.tar.gz: no space left on device
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The pipeline runs an image-building command to create and upload an image to Docker Hub. As you can see it needs to create a temporary tarball which apparently exhausts all the space on the device.

I expected adding more storage would fix this issue. Is there something else I needed to do? Where is the storage that I bought?

I was getting the same error before adding the storage and I was expecting the purchase of 10GB to get rid of this problem. After looking at the output of `df -h` it doesn't look any different than how it was before.

Using `docker prune` doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the command docker and gives an error.

I'm using Gitlab Sass by the way.

Comment: Where are you running your pipeline? in gitlabs runners? or on your own server using the gitlab runner agent?

Comment: On gitlab runners. The website.

Comment: The storage you bought isnt for increasing the runner your CI runs on, its for storage of things like pipeline job artifacts, container registries, your git repositories etc. you should check out the details on gitlabs SaaS runners https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html. Do you know how big your image is and any files in the repo? `The final disk space your jobs can use is less than 25 GB. Some disk space allocated to the instance is occupied by the operating system, the Docker image, and a copy of your cloned repository.`

Comment: Youc an also see the config the saas runners are using on that page which contains `"google-disk-size=25",`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle The repository uses 4.4GB. I'm not sure how big the image is. Do you know how I can solve this? How I can increase disk space for the pipeline/runner to do its job?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Can I edit the google-disk-size?

Comment: Nope this config is shown only for transparency, you cannot change anything about the girlab saas runners. Your only option would he to deploy the gitlab runner agent on your own server and use that for building the image or try to reduce the image size with multi Stage builds

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I set up the gitlab server and ran the pipeline and now I'm getting `Error: archive/tar: write too long`. I'm running it through a docker container btw.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Nevermind I figured it out. It had nothing to do with gitlab it was on my side

Comment: ah ok good to know. Did you managed to get your gitlab pipeline to complete the build? out of curiosity what was the size of your docker image

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I had a `.git` folder in the repository which my custom image builder wasn't designed to use. I don't know how big the image was but maybe about 10GB